# About exchanging foreign currency

Tags: united-kingdom, foreign-exchange, cash, inr-indian-rupee, gbp-british-pound

I have a friend in London and she has sent me a parcel with 9000 GBP in cash. How can I exchange it for rupees in India?

Comment: Why would you not do this at a bank?

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that your friend sent you a box full of Pound Sterling notes?

Comment: @DJClayworth who sends **large amount of cash** from one country to another?   In North America, it's drug dealers and other criminals.

Comment: @RonJohn I don't disagree,  but rather than outright accuse the OP of being a criminal drug dealer or their mule I thought I would ask some questions first.

Comment: @DJClayworth India isn't North America; it's *possible* that they do things Differently over there...

Comment: The answer to this question likely depends on the nationality of the OP. A non-citizen of India would likely have needed to _declare_ the nonIndian currency when entering India; else questions would definitely be asked if 9000 pounds sterling are brought in to deposit into a bank account or exchanged for Indian rupees. A _citizen_ of India would have even more issues. That being said, there are plenty of unofficial methods where an Indian citizen in need of pounds will gladly pay cash (Indian rupees) for those British banknotes at higher exchange rates than the official bank rate.

Comment: Don't exchange everything at once.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be scam. Stay away from it. One cannot legally send cash in box. Depending on the reasons there is tax implications and various provisions of foreign currency management act.

The next is more likely someone claiming to be custom official or law enforcement asking for money.

Comment: You might be right, but this doesn’t answer the question.